# youtube-dl cache to fasten download

Tags: regex, caching, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using youtube-dl under macports (osx 10.9). I like to use filters like (--match-title REGEX or --date) to download a single video of specific youtube user.

for a specific date, I use

```
 youtube-dl --date ymd ytuser:gronkh
```

filtered one

```
 youtube-dl ytuser:Gronkh --match-title '(?=.*Minecraft)(?=.*1170)'
```

In all the cases it's indexing the whole playlist of the ytuser, no matter even if I want to download a single video.

```
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 1 to 51
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 51 to 101
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 101 to 151
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 151 to 201
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 201 to 251
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 251 to 301
[youtube:user] Gronkh: Downloading video ids from 301 to 351
```

I thought this happens just first for the fist time for a new youtube user but this happens all the time for the same user, which is taking hell of time to download a single video. I know that I can use URL for a single video but I want to automate with filter based script.

I also tried specifying cache directory which did nothing, I can see any cache files

```
 youtube-dl --cache-dir ~/Downloads/test/ ytuser:gronkh
```

Is there any way to fast-up this process? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your regular expression is too broad. Try to make it more specific:

```
youtube-dl ytuser:Gronkh --match-title 'Minecraft[^#]+#\d+'
```